# How to by default Open expand Expandable Listview Groups

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-scrollview

Hi i am beginner in android and in my app i need to add Expandable Listview on Scrollview

I have added and implementing functionality like below for adding ExpandableListview on Scrollview now it's working fine

But according to my Case by default Expandable ListView groups need to expand how can i do this

can some one help me please

### Main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout">
        </include>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:groupIndicator="@null" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

## MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

    ArrayList<AvailableTimingsBean> availableTimingsBeanArrayList;
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        availableTimingsBeanArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        AvailableTimingsBean availableTimingsBean = new AvailableTimingsBean();
        availableTimingsBean.setFromDay("Mon");
        availableTimingsBean.setToDay("Thurs");

        TimingsBean timingsBean = new TimingsBean();
        timingsBean.setFromTime("10:00AM");
        timingsBean.setToTime("12:00AM");
        ArrayList<TimingsBean> timingsBeanArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        timingsBeanArrayList.add(timingsBean);

        availableTimingsBean.setTimings(timingsBeanArrayList);
        availableTimingsBeanArrayList.add(availableTimingsBean);

        MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(this,availableTimingsBeanArrayList);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                setListViewHeight(parent,groupPosition);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param listView
     * @param group
     */
    private void setListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView,
                                   int group) {

        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter) listView.getExpandableListAdapter();

        int totalHeight = 0;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
                View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);
            groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

            totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group))
                    || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group))) {

                for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {

                    View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,
                            listView);

                    listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
            }
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        int height = totalHeight
                + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getGroupCount() - 1));
        if (height < 10)
            height = 200;
        params.height = height;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

## Adapter:

```
public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<AvailableTimingsBean> availableTimingsBeanArrayList;
    private Context context;

    public MyExpandableAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AvailableTimingsBean> availableTimingsBeanArrayList) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
        this.availableTimingsBeanArrayList = availableTimingsBeanArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        try {

            System.out.println("getChildView");

            final TimingsBean childObj = availableTimingsBeanArrayList.
                    get(groupPosition).getTimings().get(childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_available_timings_child_items_layout, null);
            }

            TextView fromTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fromTime_id);
            TextView toTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toTime_id);
            fromTime.setText(childObj.getFromTime());
            toTime.setText(childObj.getToTime());

            return convertView;

        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        try {

            System.out.println("getGroupView");
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_available_timings_header_items, null);
            }

            TextView fromDay = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fromday_textview);
            TextView toDay = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.today_textview);
            fromDay.setText(availableTimingsBeanArrayList.get(groupPosition).getFromDay());
            toDay.setText(availableTimingsBeanArrayList.get(groupPosition).getToDay());

            return convertView;

        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

        return availableTimingsBeanArrayList.get(groupPosition).getTimings().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return availableTimingsBeanArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `getGroupView` method in the Adapter class.

```
View v = super.getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);
ExpandableListView mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) parent;
mExpandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
return v;
```

Comment: i am adding ExpandableListview on SCroll view that's why i customized some code as like my above code